# Draw a Link and Graphic over another graphic

Tags: html, css

I have a picture on a page, and I simply want to draw a link with a small graphic in the upper left corner of the picture. Is there any way to do this? to overlap it on the picture appropriately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this would work (recommend moving the inline CSS to a stylesheet of course):

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div>
         <img src="backgroundimg.png">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
         <a href="foo.html"><img src="smallgraphic.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `position:absolute` will place that div relative to a container with `position` set, in this case at left 0 top 0. So that means it will end up in the top left of the same element that the 'backgroundimg' is placed in.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Replace attribute "url" by "src".

Answer (score 1):

Don't use more divs than you need.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <img src="..." />
  </a>
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simplify:

```
<div style="background:url(yourimage.jpg); position:relative;">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
         <a href="somewhere.html"><img src="inner.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div style="background:url(yourimage.jpg); position:relative;">
  <a href="somewhere.html"><img src ="innerimage.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"/></a>
</div>
```

or:

```
    <div style="background:url(yourimage.jpg); position:relative;">
      <a href="somewhere.html" style="position:absolute; left:0; 
top:0;display:block;width:100px;height:100px;"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you're setting a background, it's not necessary to set position:absolute, as it will overlap the background in any case.