# How to display/add play button on youtube image?

Tags: youtube

I have embedded the youtube image from youtube server which is "http://img.youtube.com/vi/0.jpg", now there is no play button shows up on middle of the image as we see usually any youtube videos!

I tried to use the following code to get an image on top of the youtube image but it shows bigger picture, i know why

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#video">
<img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/play_button.png" no-repeat width: 0px height:0px; style="background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $youtubeid ; ?>/0.jpg) transparent" width="180" height="150"/>
```

```
<div id ="video">
// here is my embedded youtube usual code
</div>
```

both images shown in 180 x 150 size, but thats not what i want.

I want youtube image will be shown in 180 x 150 size and play button image (play_button.png) will be display in middle of the youtube image in small size.

Any clue in css or coding in php will be great favour.

Comment: While you might be building a website in WordPress, this has nothing to do with WordPress itself.  You're looking for CSS/layout help ... you need to position the play button PNG on top of the YouTube thumbnail. As I said, a CSS/HTML issue. Please post to StackOverflow instead.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted out quite easily. Just create an image with play button middle and make the surround transparent and then I put this image on top of the youtube thumbnail image. it worked, but video image gets realigned, but it does not look bad though.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#bizgenevideo">
<img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/play-button.png" style="background: url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $youtubeid ; ?>/0.jpg) " width="180" height="148"/>
```

Comment: It's not perfect but it's quick and I like it ! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a web service

the halgatewood service was taken down, guess too many people bombarded him :)
now it is on github

https://halgatewood.com/easily-add-play-buttons-to-youtube-video-thumbnails/
https://github.com/halgatewood/youtube-thumbnail-enhancer

Here is another service that does the same thing (as suggested by muktesh patel):

http://www.giikers.com/iwc

### old answer:

http://halgatewood.com/youtube/

Like this:
http://halgatewood.com/youtube/i/youtube_id.jpg

For example:
http://halgatewood.com/youtube/i/aIgY20n3n0Y.jpg

Related question: [How to overlay a play button over a YouTube thumbnail image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123489/how-to-overlay-a-play-button-over-a-youtube-thumbnail-image)

Comment: @kleopatra If you read the question and the answer you would realize that this IS the end point answer... It is a link to a service that generates thumbnails, I can't provide their code nor should I need to nor do many people want it. Please read before spamming complaints, thank you.

Comment: reading wasn't the problem - recognizing was ;-) Thanks for the heads up