# How to place an image on the other image in the WebView in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, webview

I have added an image to webView as a header. So now I want to add another image on to it as a button image for that I need to use anchor tag, But how to add image on top of other image using html code in objecitvie-c.

Please help me out of this.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: You can overlay it just using CSS/HTML code, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403478/css-how-to-overlay-images)

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice alternative to your problem would be to create a new composite image using photosop. This image will contain both the images(header and the button image).
 Follow this link to create the image - http://www.elated.com/articles/fading-one-image-into-another/ and ignore its Fill the layer mask with a gradient topic.
And then add it your webview using html code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Shruti: Can't we do it with code. Because, If we use photoshop then whole image is selected when tapping instead of only button.

Comment: Ok tell me actually what do you want to do. If you need to add a button at the header that is apart from ur html file then just add an image and a button to it on your view and then below it start your webview and display your url in it. Will this help you.

Comment: NO, It will not help. If we add to the view then the imageButton is not scrollable. It should be on the header image, selectable and scrollable.

Comment: @Laura: Is it Shruti...? I got it solved by adding local images using html code.

Comment: @Madan Mohan: Thanx :) Ok fine. Then I would exactly wanna know what you did.

Comment: @Laura:Our native is same:).Html using div tags I added both images and with anchor tag I added button Image. thats all.