# Programmatically moving an image atop another image

Tags: charts

I would like to figure out how to programmatically move the bear face and popsicle stick horizontally 1/28th of the way for each day of the month. I need to do this for charts ranging from 25 to 35 days in which the face would have to move 1/25th to 1/35th of the way each day, respectively. The reason for not doing this manually is that I'm trying to pull a different bear face each day from a database. Not sure how to attack this.

[Bear Chart](http://www.thedailycramp.com/images/chart_bear.png)

Comment: April 1 isn't for another 10 days

Answer (score 0):

this will depend on the language, but you will want some sort of image processing library.

Say, if you use PHP, then GD is a good start.

In Python, look at PIL.

In Ruby, there is RMagick.

Answer (score 0):

You can [overlay](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/css-tutorials/css-position-text-images-050629-1066/) one image over another [using plain CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403478/css-how-to-overlay-images)