# z-index for background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

can we set z-index to background property?

I have one div, in which dynamic content place with ajax request, which contains table with background image.

Now issue is, after 1st request table with image background set in div.
when second request send , in beforeSend method one code is written to show processing image while response come to div. 
But processing image can not be shown as there is all ready image in table background set ...

Issue is div back ground is on base level, which is hide by table background image

Can I manage it with Z-Index some way or any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403478/css-how-to-overlay-images .... explains the overlay of images.

Answer (score 1):

May be add z-index for the processing image with higher value than the z-index value of the background image.