# Using overlays on multiple images on one web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new to coding and I'm using codepen.io to get better, so ignore the actual content its something to practice on. Anyways I'm trying to do multiple overlays on images on one page. I can't seem to figure out how to get the overlays to be on their individual images.

here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/ToxicCookie/pen/RmXYLv?editors=1000

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        background-color: #d7c2fc;
        font-family: Courier New, monospace;
      }
      #title {
        text-align: Center;
        font-size: 50px;
      }
      .container {
       position: relative;
       width: 50%;
       }
      .image {
       display: block;
       width: 300px;
       height: 250px;
       }
      .overlay {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       height: 250px;
       width: 300px;
       opacity: 0;
       transition: .5s ease;
       background-color: #008CBA;
       }
      .container:hover .overlay {
       opacity: 1;
       }
      .text {
       color: white;
       font-size: 20px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       text-align: center;
       background-color: #008CBA;
       }
      #animals {
        position: fixed;
      }
      #earth{
        position: fixed;
        left: 320px;
      }
      #body{
        position: fixed;
        left: 630px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id= "title"> Why be Vegan?</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <img id="animals" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7291/11910205046_d9844787b2_b.jpg" alt="animals" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Animals</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <img id="earth" src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.540939652.0382/flat,550x550,075,f.u2.jpg" alt="earth" class="image" >
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Earth</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <img id="body" src="https://www.uuwaco.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/veggieheart.jpg" alt="body" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Body</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Think this was asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086385/how-to-make-in-css-an-overlay-over-an-image

Comment: @TemaniAfif You better not replace code in quetion with the answer. No? :)

Comment: @ItangSanjana I didn't replace with the answer. I copied the code from codepen to the question because we need the code within the question and not as external link. The OP can easily edit the codepen to fix the issue and the question will become useless

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see. Pardon my misunderstood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the image to be `position:fixed` which is the culprit. Remove it and make the container `inline-block` instead:

```css
* {
  background-color: #d7c2fc;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
}

#title {
  text-align: Center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title"> Why be Vegan?</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img id="animals" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7291/11910205046_d9844787b2_b.jpg" alt="animals" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Animals</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="earth" src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.540939652.0382/flat,550x550,075,f.u2.jpg" alt="earth" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Earth</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="body" src="https://www.uuwaco.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/veggieheart.jpg" alt="body" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 222px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figcaption {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7291/11910205046_d9844787b2_b.jpg"
       alt="The beautiful MDN logo.">
  <figcaption>Animal</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Notes:

- Use semantic HTML element if possible. i.e `<figure>` & `<figcaption>`
- Add CSS relative position to the parent node of the absolute/fixed position.
- Make image responsive if possible `height: auto; max-width: 100%`. Better to also use the media or image source element `<source>`.