# How do you darken an image without using filter?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to darken an image without using the filter property, since the filter property isn't compatible with all IEs at all even with vendor prefixes. I need to make a website which is also compatible with at least IE 11. Is there any brilliant method to darken an image without using the filter property in CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make in CSS an overlay over an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086385/how-to-make-in-css-an-overlay-over-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Try overlapping the image with a `div` and give it some `opacity` with color `black`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an overlay div would help.
`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5LKVYZUWJ1Uj-VymZDykSDIjBfmQfov7NPdAPdmvjWhtHPxHFSw&s" />
</div>

<style>
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}
</style>
```

`
https://jsfiddle.net/devatquarxps/fq94ov7h/7/